# Matching on double quote pair with quotes inside

Tags: regex

I have a string that has phrases wrapped in quotes, that can have quotes inside them.

I need to match on the outside pair, so for example,

String: `THIS IS "THE STRING "WE" ARE WORKING" ON`

I would need to find `"THE STRING "WE" ARE WORKING"

I have tried `\"([^\"]*?)\"` but it finds `"THE STRING", "ARE WORKING ON"`.

Is this possible with regex?

Comment: Just for clarity, I think you have a typo: shouldn't `THIS IS "THE STRING "WE" ARE WORKING" ON` result in `"THE STRING "WE" ARE WORKING"`?

Comment: Sorry, yes you're right. I've changed it there now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to use:

```
(\".*\")
```

...greedily matching until you find the last `"` character.

Comment: Yeah but it will also match internal quotes, which the OP doesn't want.

Comment: Damn, so easy. Thanks a mill!

Answer (score 0):

```
\".+\"
```

The + is greedy, it should match the last double quote.

Comment: Yeah but it will also match internal quotes, which the OP doesn't want.